# jQuery check for click with if/else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check to see if an id was clicked.  If it is do something, otherwise do something else.  The else part is working but the click part doesn't seem to be.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#rotators").click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
  });

  if ($('#rotators').data('clicked')) {
    $("#rotators").css({
      "overflow": "auto"
    });
    $("#rotators").css({
      "height": "auto"
    });
  } else {

    setInterval(function() {

      if ($("#rotatelist > a:last").is(":visible")) {
        $("#rotatelist a:last").after($("#rotatelist a:first"));
        $("#rotators").css({
          "overflow": "hidden"
        });
        $("#rotators").css({
          "height": "30px"
        });
      }

    }, 500);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotators">
  <span id="rotatelist"><a href="#">solutions</a><a href="#">film</a><a href="#">seo</a><a href="#">pr</a><a href="#">web development</a><a href="#">marketing</a></span>
</div>
```

The fiddle for it is here.  It doesn't throw an error but the click check just isn't working.

https://jsfiddle.net/cetx8vaL/

EDIT: Per the (excellent) feedback I will explain my goal.  I want each  to "rotate" one at a time, however, if the #rotators  is clicked I want it to stop rotating and show all of the  elements as a vertical list.

Comment: `if ($('#rotators').data('clicked'))` will always be false because you only check it once (on page load).

Comment: You're also not checking for `$('#rotators').data('clicked')` in your interval function...

Comment: You only ever check `data('clicked')` when the page loads. It would make far more sense to put all the logic which executes within that `if` statement in the `click` handler, as then you know the element has actually been clicked.

Comment: you only evaluate `if/else` parts one time - on page load

Comment: In fact, it may be easier if you described your goal in the question as I am certain there's a better way to achieve whatever it is

Comment: I've edited my answer to respond to the edit in your question FYI. I would have commented instead of editing my answer but I've only just earned that privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to move your `if ($('#rotators').data('clicked')) {` block inside of the `setInterval` function. The reason for this is the if/else is evaluated on page load so it's immediately evaluated as `$('#rotators').data('clicked') === undefined` and as a result fires the `setInterval` function perpetually.

If you move the if/else clause inside the `setInterval` function it will check whether the element has been clicked every 500ms.

The below code seems to achieve what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#rotators").click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#rotators').data('clicked')) 
    {
        $("#rotators").css({
                            "overflow": "auto"
        });
        $("#rotators").css({
                            "height": "auto"
        });
    } 
    else if ($("#rotatelist > a:last").is(":visible")) 
    {
        $("#rotatelist a:last").after($("#rotatelist a:first"));
        $("#rotators").css({
                            "overflow": "hidden"
        });
        $("#rotators").css({
                            "height": "30px"
        });
    }
}, 500);

});
```

As Rory said in a comment

> In fact, it may be easier if you described your goal in the question
>   as I am certain there's a better way to achieve whatever it is

Your question may be an example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- and it might be worth explaining the goal you're trying to achieve with the above code. Either way, I hope my answer helps your understanding somewhat.

Edit: After seeing your desired goal, is this the kind of thing you're looking for re: making the list vertical? https://jsfiddle.net/0kn72ofp/

At the moment your list of links doesn't rotate one at a time, it seems to shift a few characters at a time. If you want it to rotate one link at a time I'd suggest looking into something like jQuery UI's Slide or slideToggle effects.